# Understanding a basic math concept from computer science perspective

Tags: sequences-and-series

So basically i am studying computer science but i dont have avery strong mathematical background , however some things i get and something i dont get and kind of wonder what is the wisdom behind them

I am having trouble with this statement which i assume is probably very basic maths

if we have a sequence of numbers

1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9

or unordered sequence of numbers

3, 5, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7

and we had to search through each member of this sequence if we are looking if a number is member of the set/sequence

why is it assumed that if N is the cardinality of the set/sequence that the average search time for a number that is IN the set is N/2 for both the ordered and unordered set

also given that the ordered set is searched in logarithmic fashion i.e search the centre and see if number is less then the middle number and keep dividing etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the sum of **total** search time to search each number in the set once is
$$T_{total}=\sum_{k=1}^{N}k=\frac{N(N+1)}{2}$$
And then the average search time is
$$T_{average}=\frac{T_{total}}{N}=\frac{N+1}{2}\approx \frac{N}{2}$$

So the point is that $\frac{N}{2}$ is based on the assumption that he/she would not try to search smartly even if numbers are ordered.

If its an ordered set and those numbers are approximately uniformly distributed, and if he/she is smart enough and is eager to minimize the search time then the average search time will be $\log_2 N$ as you know.

Comment: wouldnt the total search time be just N? 

going through each one would be just the number of items?

i can understand that the sum of them would be the T total formula , but to go through them wouldnt depend on summing their values?

Comment: Assuming that the start point of searching is always fixed then the search time would be minimum 1 and maximum N. The total time I said above was to sum of 7 searches for the set {1,2,4,6,7,8,9}.

Comment: Assume the sequence is wrapped back as a circle (in case that you don't like the fixed search start point is the first number), and you stop searching when you found the number.

Comment: okay i think i understand

so what your saying is to SEARCH EACH number would be the summation , so that to search for 1 would be 1 to search for 2 would be 2, to search for 4 would be 3 to search for 6 would be 5 etc and hence why to search for all 7 would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 +5 +6 +7 , is this what your getting at?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. You can choose 6 as the fixed starting point and you get the same result (assuming you wrap back to 1 if 9 is not the number you're searching).

Comment: what about the average? thats another concept i dont understand in all of this?

Comment: The average is total divided by the number of numbers (items). That is $\frac{1+2+3+4+5+6+7}{7}=\frac{28}{7}$, just like you would calculate average of any group.

Comment: but does it have a more precise and deeper meaning or is it more abstract? does it hold any truth ? or is it really no value in reality?

Comment: in the example you used 28/7 is 4 which is the middle point of those numbers, so is the average the middle point in the group?

Comment: I think it holds some value and useful. Depending on how you program or design an algorithm, some strategy may give you order of N $(O(N))$ and some other may give you $O(N^2)$ or some other $O(\log(N))$. So I think whether $\frac{N}{2}$ or $N$ or $N-1$ is not that critical but you should just understand that it is $O(N)$ in this linear non-strategic search.

Comment: Yes, you can think that way too. Just think about it for a while. At some moment, it will become more clear to you all of a sudden. That's how you learn.